# Word2vec with Conv1D for text classification confusion

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, word2vec, multiclass-classification

I am doing text classification and plan to use word2vec word embeddings and pass it to Conv1D layers for text classification. I have a [dataframe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxe63rkqkaqji1x/emotion_merged_dataset.csv?dl=0) which contains the texts and corresponding labels(sentiments). I have used the gensim module and used word2vec algorithm to generate the word-embedding model. The code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
df=pd.read_csv('emotion_merged_dataset.csv')
texts=df['text']
labels=df['sentiment']
df_tokenized=df.apply(lambda row: word_tokenize(row['text']), axis=1)
model = Word2Vec(df_tokenized, min_count=1)
```

I plan to use CNN and use this word-embedding model. But how should I use this word-embedding model for my cnn? What should be my input?

I plan to use something like(obviously not with the same hyper-parameters):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=max_len))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(5))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
```

Can somebody help me out and point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to load the word2vec weights in the embedding layer
you also need to convert the words to integers so that the embeddings layer is able to convert each word to a vector, for that purpose word2vec has a dictionary that maps each word to an integer

Comment: @Kailegh Can you please elaborate, preferably with some code? Thanks for the lightning fast response.

Comment: ahahha i am working right now, I will give you an elaborated answer this evening if no one else has done so yet
although I usually download the word embedding file my self instead of taking the gensim one, but I that wont be a problem

Comment: @Kaleigh Can you  also tell me about the alternative method you mentioned without using gensim? Thanks

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Comment: @Kaleigh Actually I got it working on my own. Thanks. Can you answer my latest question on CNN about low validation accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, I hope it is still useful for you.
Depending on your application you may need to download a specific wordembedding file, for example here yoou have the [Glove files](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/)

```
EMBEDDING_FILE='glove.6B.50d.txt'

embed_size = 50 # how big is each word vector
max_features = 20000 # how many unique words to use (i.e num rows in embedding vector)
maxlen = 100 # max number of words in a comment to use

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
nb_words = min(max_features, len(word_index))
embedding_matrix = np.random.normal(emb_mean, emb_std, (nb_words, embed_size))
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if i >= max_features: continue
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None: embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

#this is how you load the weights in the embedding layer
inp = Input(shape=(maxlen,))
x = Embedding(max_features, embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix])(inp)
```

I took this code from [Jeremy Howard](https://www.kaggle.com/jhoward/improved-lstm-baseline-glove-dropout), I think this is all you need, if you want to load other file the process is pretty similar, usually you just have to change the loading file